# SQL Server: How to create local server group?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

In SQL Server 2008 EE, how can I create a local server group? And also, what is the benefit of using local server groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Server Group.. a little search on SQL Books oline gave me [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190733.aspx).